# Регулярное выражение для формулы

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Имеется следующая строка:

```
\dfrac{3\sqrt{2}-5}{\sqrt{2}-1}+\dfrac{\sqrt{24}-\sqrt{300}}{\sqrt{3}}
```

С неё нужно взять: `3\sqrt{2}-5` , `\sqrt{2}-1` , `\sqrt{24}-\sqrt{300}` , `\sqrt{3}`
Я написал РВ, но оно работает некорректно, я понимаю причину (я разрешаю, чтобы были скобки {}, чтобы можно было взять данные, но именно они служат их "ограничителями"), но не знаю, как её можно обойти:

```
"[dfrac]\\{([a-z0-9+-{}]+)\\}+\\{+([a-z0-9+-{}]+)\\}"
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь, подтолкните в правильном направлении.

Comment: а вы не думаете что причина в этом - [dfrac] - символьный клас который должен совпасть с ОДНИМ символом

Comment: Не надо парсить арифметическое выражение регулярками. И в базовом синтаксисе получить только внешний уровень скобок нельзя.

Comment: Если уровень вложенности скобок только один (т.е. не может быть `{...{...{...}...}...}`, а только `{...{...}...{...}...}`), то можно использовать следующее выражение: `\{(?:[^{}]*(?:\{[^{}]*\})*[^{}]*)*\}` (с экранированием не знаю как будет), проверял [здесь](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html). Аналогично можно сделать и для большего уровня вложенности, только регулярка разрастется.

Comment: @s_klepcha , нет, если в группе убрать "{}", а в строке "sqrt{2}...", то все работает

Comment: @Qwertiy подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если задача конкретно такая, то можно попробовать подобное регулярное выражение:

```
\\dfrac{(.+)}{(.+)}\+\\dfrac{(.+)}{(.+)}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bDhENijbSdivPRCm)

Как заметил [@s_klepcha](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/189466/s-klepcha), у вас действительно немного странно записано начало регулярного выражения, квадратные скобки там ни к чему. Описывать содержимое внутри `dfrac{}` я не стал, так как оно однозначно определяется по структуре строки.

**UPD**
С учётом всех экранирований, итоговое регулярное выражение будет такое:

```
"\\\\dfrac\\{(.+)\\}\\{(.+)\\}\\+\\\\dfrac\\{(.+)\\}\\{(.+)\\}"
```

**UPD2**
Важно помнить, что это выражение будет работать только на точно такой структуре строк, и если вам потребуется более сложная работа с синтаксисом формул, потребуется писать полноценный парсер.

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись! В конечном итоге необходимо получить регулярное выражение вида: `\\\\dfrac\\{(.+)\\}\\{(.+)\\}` , т.к. работать оно будет с разными строками, в одной может быть только 1 формула, в другой несколько, подскажите, как это реализовать? Если использовать этот вариант `\\\\dfrac\\{(.+)\\}\\{(.+)\\}`, то он некорректно отрабатывает.

Comment: Выражение, работающее в общем случае составить не получится, так как для этого недостаточно мощности регулярных выражений. Попробуйте найти парсер TeX для Java и воспользоваться им.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!